# How to remove the duplicate region plotting the region on Microsoft Bing Map?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

We have integrated the bing map chart as the provided url based plugin using. But we are facing the issue related to displaying the duplicate values of region.

Is there way to plot only one region on Microsoft Map Chart ?
like in the attached document Asia is getting applied twice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to do that. What you are seeing is known as world wrap and is what allows you to pan the map horizontally infinitely, like spinning a globe, and also a requirement to support rendering shapes that cross the anti-meridian (-180/180 longitude, for example a line from Sydney, Australia to California)